# Como "quebrar" div em duas colunas?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

Estou utilizando o WordPress, minha seção Blog está organizada da seguinte forma:

[image: Exemplo 1]

Estou utilizando simplesmente `{display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}` que no caso o resultado é como o do primeiro exemplo. O resultado que quero alcançar é:

[image: Exemplo 2]

Não criei duas divs para o conteúdo por justamente serem artigos do Blog, ou seja, devem ficar na ordem de postagem. Se eu quebrar em duas divs o `widget de artigos`, que é padrão do WordPress, repetiria em ambas as divs. **Enfim, gostaria que as postagens do blog ficassem em ordem, numa mesma div e em duas colunas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sabia ao certo como procurar tal resposta então se houver duplicata, me avisem. Muito obrigado desde já (:

Comment: Cara vc mesmo está fazendo o Tema? Se possível coloque seu html/css. Vc está usando Boostrap??

Comment: @hugocsl então Hugo na verdade é um theme da comunidade WP que estou modificando eu mesmo...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na `div` pai, você precisaria definir duas propriedades que definem como os elementos devem agir quando precisam fazer essa quebra de linha.

A primeira seria `flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;`. Ela informa qual será a direção em que o elemento "crescerá".

A segunda seria `flex-wrap: nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse;`. Ela informa como deve ser feita a quebra de linhas do elemento.

Para facilitar, existe a versão encurtada essas duas propriedades, que é a `flex-flow`, a qual você passa como primeiro argumento a direção e em segundo a quebra de linha.

Fiz de forma bem rápida um código que acho que vai te ajudar. Você pode ver [funcionando no CodePen](https://codepen.io/victorjordan95/pen/YLGYMM).

Um link bem legal para ter como referência é o do [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), nele contém uma explicação detalhada de propriedades do flexbox.

Comment: era exatamente o que eu estava precisando, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Aqui tem um modelo que vai quebrando a linha a cada 3 itens. Tudo responsivo usando `flex-box`. Deixei o `item-7` para vc ver que ele vai quebrar conforme a lista for crescendo. ***OBS***: fiz um comment no CSS sobre como ajustar as margens entre um box e outro se vc quiser mudar a distancia.

**Explicação:** A propriedade que faz a linha de itens quebrar é a `flex-wrap:wrap`, e ela quebra de 3 em 3 por que cada bos tem a largura de 1/3, logo 3 `.box` somam 100% e o item 4 acaba sendo "jogado" para a linha de baixo. Documentação oficial do flex-box: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/

Se quiser que o `box item-7` fique alinhado no meio basta colocar `justify-content:cente`r no `.wrapper`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    background-color: silver;
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 2rem); /* calco para descontar a margem da largura do box se aumenta a marge tem que ajustar aqui tb */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">imte 1</div>
    <div class="box">imte 2</div>
    <div class="box">imte 3</div>
    <div class="box">imte 4</div>
    <div class="box">imte 5</div>
    <div class="box">imte 6</div>
    <div class="box">imte 7</div>
</div>
```